# js где взять just-validate.min.js?

Tags: javascript

При скачивании и открытии архива с GitHub, там куча разных файлов и папок. Мне нужен именно `just-validate.min.js`.

P.S. Не надо умничать и нести всякую хрень как Darth. Программист сразу поймет вопрос, и не будет говорить 'переименуй любой файл в just-validate'.

Comment: возьмите любой файл из архива и переименуйте как именно вам нужно

Comment: @Darth там каждый файл отдельную роль играет, вы серьезно что-ли

Comment: Вы поставили  вопрос досаточно конкретно - как получить файл с определенным названием. про какие-то роли в вопросе ничего нет. таким образом, проще всего вам будет переименовать любой из файлов и вы получите файл с нужным названием. можно создать новый файл с таким названием и положить его туда, результат будет идентичен - вы получите "именно `just-validate.min.js`" (с)

Comment: @Darth вы прекрасно поняли вопрос, но решили докопаться? Лучше б так помогали

Comment: Можно с гитхаба скачать архив и поискать в нём файлы с раширением js. и точно что-то да найдётся

Comment: А вообще даже на оф сайте https://just-validate.dev/   если внимательно глянуть, то в полне можно увидеть URL с нужным файлом

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я же не просто так задал вопрос, там куча этих js

Comment: Как такового `min.js` файла там вроде нет, так как на гите нет dist директории чем Вам не подходит вариант из [Getting Started](https://just-validate.dev/docs/intro)?

Comment: @Nqweqweqwe ну ищи там конкретный файл...алё

Comment: Но в том же гитхабе прям на главной странице вполне нарисован URL со скриптом

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что достаточно внимательно почитать доку в том же гитхабе.... *facepalm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делов-то на минуту, но надо зачем-то вопрос задать.

1. Ищем библиотеку: https://www.npmjs.com/package/just-validate
2. Ищем cdn для неё: https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/just-validate
   `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/just-validate@4.3.0/dist/just-validate.production.min.js`

А вот уж версию сам перебирай.

Comment: *"1. Ищем..... 2. Ищем......"* --- Да не надо ничего искать так..... Что на гитхабе, что на оф. сайте, что на сайте npmjs прямо на заглавных страницах адрес подключения написан...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а, ну да, на npm есть, если вниз промотать описание. А до официального сайта я вообще не дошёл.